# Storing Button id's into a variable onclick

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In a jsp file, I have created two buttons each having unique id of their own, on clicking the buttons gets deleted or  hidden and these deleted buttons id are displayed at the bottom. Now my requirement is to add the button id's to an ArrayList as they are being deleted.

I tried using

```
window.location.replace("array.jsp?arr="+arr);
```

the problem with this is that the page is getting refreshed and deleted buttons re-appers.

How do I realize this.

Below is the code That I have tried

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />

<%
    ArrayList del= new ArrayList();
    String ele=null;
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr=new Array();

    function hButton(id)
    {

        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style","background:white");   
        arr.push(id);    
        document.getElementById("id-show").textContent=arr+"</br>";         
    }

    function showId(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("title",id);
    }

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="big_wrapper">      
    <table>
            <tr>    
            <td>    <button class="btn"  style="background:red" id="1,1" onmouseOver='showId(this.id)' onclick='hButton(this.id)';> </button>   </td>               
            </tr>

            <tr>    

            <td>    <button class="btn"  style="background:red" id="2,1" onmouseOver='showId(this.id)' onclick='hButton(this.id)';> </button>   </td>               
            </tr>   

    </table>
    </div>


 <div id="id-show"> </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: I think you are deleting nodes in client side only. And the deleted buttons reappears while reloading the page. Can you be more clear how you are deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

To get the `id` of any element you can use jQuery like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the ids in an array you use the push function .

```
var arr = new Array();

$('button').click(function() {
   arr.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```